# pygame.time.set_timer() - 4 2 the floor click

Tags: python, pygame

Why doesn't this play my click.wav every 444ms? it just seems to play it at random intervals.

```
import pygame

pygame.init()
size = (700, 500)
screen = pygame.display.set_mode(size)

pygame.display.set_caption("444ms click")
done = False
clock = pygame.time.Clock()
noise = pygame.mixer.Sound("click.wav")
pygame.time.set_timer(1, 444)

while not done:
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            done = True
        if event.type == 1:
            noise.play()

    clock.tick(60)

pygame.quit()
```

and if anyone knows how I could do this more easily that would be good.

Thank You!

@JFSebeastian: Here's the output for [the code](https://gist.github.com/zed/dcc6ae76487add302371):

```
447
436
443
430
449
431
448
432
910
7
407
447
442
432
446
431
448
432
450
432
446
472
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `event.type == pygame.USEREVENT + 1`, otherwise the event may be generated for other reasons (whatever `1` event type corresponds to in pygame) that is why it appears random.

---

The output for [the code](https://gist.github.com/zed/dcc6ae76487add302371) shows that the time intervals are mostly `440±10` ms with the exception of `910`, `7` pair.

`±10` milliseconds for a timer sounds normal for `fps=60`. To get tighter timings, you could use `clock.tick()` instead of `clock.tick(60)`.

`910`, `7` pair suggests that `set_timer()`/`tick()` might use a `time.sleep()` analog somewhere. `time.sleep()` may sleep more than specified that is why the timer may skip a beat. Try `clock.tick_busy_loop()` that shouldn't sleep and see if you can reproduce the skips.

Comment: Hi JF Sebastian and thanks for your advice. The code now has pygame.USEREVENT + 1 in place of the number 1 where you said and in the set_timer argument and seems slightly better but still not right. The clicks are mostly played in a kind of swing rhythm like this (1 = note, 0 = rest) 110110110110... Why do you think that is!?!?

Comment: @TomEdwards: you need to change the `set_timer()` call too (replace `1` with `USEREVENT+1`). [I've tested it and it works fine on my system.](https://gist.github.com/zed/dcc6ae76487add302371)

Comment: @JFSebeastian: Thanks. I replaced 1 in set_timer() with `pygame.USEREVENT+1` and it was still random. Then I tried it without the 'pygame.' and just wrote `USEREVENT+1` as the first argument, like you said and it gave me the error `NameError: name 'USEREVENT' is not defined` cheers.

Comment: @TomEdwards: it must be clear from the context that I meant `pygame.USEREVENT` when I said `USEREVENT`. You should be capable to resolve such issues (`NameError`) yourself. Could you run [the code I've linked above](https://gist.github.com/zed/dcc6ae76487add302371) and post its output in your question?

Comment: @JFSebeastian: You're right, sorry. I ran the code and printed some of the output in my question as you asked. Still random timings and looks like it, from the output, especially the `910 7`. something wrong with my system maybe?

Comment: @TomEdwards: I've added the explanation for the code results and some possible workarounds.

Comment: @JFSebeastian: Thanks, I changed your code to use `Clock.tick_busy_loop()` and it was a good improvement. The output was consistently 440 but although the click was much more pulse like, it still skips every 2-3 beats.

Comment: @TomEdwards: when you say "skips" do you mean the value is significantly larger/smaller (like `910`, `7`)? I run the code that uses `clock.tick()` (note: lowercase `clock`) 4 hours without a pause: it has *not* skipped even once. How many CPU cores do you have? Is your system busy?

Comment: @JFSebeastian: The value is consistant its the sound only that is skipping, it reminds me of when you loop something on media player, its always choppy not a perfect loop. which makes me think that its just not the best way to achieve what I'm trying to do, I think i just need something more acurate. Maybe however, it will work with images which is my actual motive for doing it so I will try that and see what the results are. I'll post my results once I've worked it out. Is there any other way of syncronising events to a beat?

Comment: @TomEdwards: if you need precision bettern than 10s milliseconds, you need to be more specific about your code (showing images may or may not produce a difference compared to playing a sound but it is one less variable to think about). What happens if you try [this code](http://stackoverflow.com/a/26609843/4279) on your system?