# How can I create a walking animation? (Pygame, python)

Tags: python, pygame

Here is my code.

```
jack_right_1 = pg.image.load(os.path.join(img_folder, "jack_right_1.png")).convert()
jack_right_2 = pg.image.load(os.path.join(img_folder, "jack_right_2.png")).convert()
jack_right_3 = pg.image.load(os.path.join(img_folder, "jack_right_3.png")).convert()

player_images = [jack_right_1, jack_right_2, jack_right_3]

class Player(pg.sprite.Sprite):
    def __init__(self):
        pg.sprite.Sprite.__init__(self)
        self.image = player_images
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect()
        self.pos = vec(WIDTH - 650, HEIGHT - 700)
        self.standing = False
        self.vel = vec(0, 0)
        self.acc = vec(0, 0)

    def update(self):
        self.acc = vec(0, PLAYER_GRAVITY)
        keystate = pg.key.get_pressed()
        if keystate[pg.K_LEFT]:
            player.image = pg.image.load(player_images[counter])
            counter = (counter + 1) % len(player_images)
```

For some reason, whenever I try to run it, it says that 'list' object has no attribute 'get_rect'. I know you cannot get a rect from a list, but then **how do you make an image list and get the rect for each image?**

Answer (score 1):

The `image` attribute of a `pygame.sprite.Sprite` has to be a single surface. Assign only the first image of the `player_images` to `self.image`. The error is raised because you call `self.rect = self.image.get_rect()` but your `self.image` is a list which doesn't have a `get_rect` method.

You also need an attribute to keep track of the index of the current image (I call it `self.counter` in the following example).

Now to update the image, you increment the `self.counter` and use modulo `len(player_images)` to avoid IndexErrors. Then you use the `self.counter` index to update the `self.image` `self.image = player_images[self.counter]`.

```
class Player(pg.sprite.Sprite):

    def __init__(self):
        pg.sprite.Sprite.__init__(self)
        self.counter = 0  # Index of the current image.
        # Assign the first player image.
        self.image = player_images[self.counter]
        self.pos = vec(WIDTH - 650, HEIGHT - 700)
        # Now get_rect works. Set the center or topleft to self.pos.
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect(center=self.pos)
        self.standing = False
        self.vel = vec(0, 0)
        self.acc = vec(0, 0)

    def update(self):
        self.acc = vec(0, PLAYER_GRAVITY)
        keystate = pg.key.get_pressed()
        if keystate[pg.K_LEFT]:
            # Increment the counter.
            self.counter = (self.counter + 1) % len(player_images)
            # And finally change the image.
            self.image = player_images[self.counter]
```

Comment: Also, don't load images in methods that get called all the time. Load them globally like `jack_right1` and then reuse them in your program. --- `pg.key.get_pressed()` should probably be called in your main loop. Then you can pass the `keystate` list to all sprites that need it.

Comment: Thank you for your help. I have it working now. But, how do I control the speed at which the image switches?

Comment: To control the animation speed, you can use a timer similar to [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44035094/6220679) and increment the image index when the time is up.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are pretty close! The problem is that `player_images` (and therefore `self.image`) actually stores a **list** of `Surface` objects rather an **individual** `Surface`. If you want to store a list of `Rect` objects, you could loop through them like so:

```
class Player(pg.sprite.Sprite):
    def __init__(self):
        pg.sprite.Sprite.__init__(self)
        self.images = player_images
        self.rects = []
        for image in self.images:
            self.rects.append(image.get_rect())
```

Alternatively, if you need a one-liner which does the same thing, consider a list comprehension instead:

```
class Player(pg.sprite.Sprite):
    def __init__(self):
        pg.sprite.Sprite.__init__(self)
        self.images = player_images
        self.rects = [image.get_rect() for image in self.images]
```

Comment: Thank you for your help!