# Enemy character is being overdrawn by game's background

Tags: python, background, pygame

I am working on a game which spawns enemies. Though once these enemies are spawned, they instantly disappear again because the background is drawn on top of them.

Is there a way to have a layer system in Pygame?

**Code to recreate the problem:**

```
import pygame
import threading
from random import randint
from time import sleep

pygame.init()
window = pygame.display.set_mode((900, 900))
bg=pygame.image.load("Background.png").convert()

def Gameplay():
    while True:  
        window.blit(bg, [0,0])
        pygame.display.update()

def spawn_enemy():
    enemyW = 50
    enemyH = 50
    enemyX = 420
    enemyY = 850
    pygame.draw.rect(window, (93,124,249),(enemyX,enemyY,enemyW, enemyH))
    print("an enemy has been spawned")
    return True # would be "return enemy" after you create your enemy entity

def EnemySpawn():
    enemy_list = [] # to maintain records of all enemies made
    while True: # make enemies forever
        sleep(randint(1,5))
        enemy_list.append(spawn_enemy()) # call our function we made above which spawns enemies

Gameplay = threading.Thread(target=Gameplay)
Gameplay.start()
EnemySpawn = threading.Thread(target=EnemySpawn)
EnemySpawn.start()
```

Comment: Of course, what do you expect? First the background is draw (`window.blit(bg, [0,0])`) and then the display is updated immediately  (`pygame.display.update()`). Nothing happens in between, so nothing else then the background is on the display. Draw the entire scene in one thread. It's a bad idea to split the drawing of the scene to different threads. You can do expensive calculations or IO handling in a thread, but not parts of the drawing.

Comment: I also want to move a character without it being stuck for 1-5 seconds so I can't put it all in one thread, can I? I feel like making a MCVE isn't actually what I should have done. Should I now post my whole code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I do not understand `pygame` and it for some reason becomes generally unresponsive when I run this, but it does generate enemies and show how one would implement a class to store their variables (perhaps a `pygame` expert could edit it to become responsive or comment what my code is doing that makes the window "freeze up"):

```
import pygame
import threading
from random import randint
from time import sleep
import random

pygame.init()
window = pygame.display.set_mode((900, 900))
bg = pygame.image.load("Background.png").convert()

class Enemy:
    def __init__(self):
        self.W = random.randint(30, 50)
        self.H = random.randint(30, 50)
        self.X = random.randint(0, 900)
        self.Y = random.randint(0, 900)

def Gameplay():
    global enemy_list
    while True:
        window.blit(bg, [0, 0])
        for enemy in enemy_list:
            pygame.draw.rect(window, (93, 124, 249), (enemy.X, enemy.Y, enemy.W, enemy.H))
        pygame.display.update()

def EnemySpawn():
    global enemy_list
    while True: # make enemies forever
        sleep(randint(1, 5))
        print("Spawned an enemy")
        enemy_list.append(Enemy()) # make an instance of our class

enemy_list = [] # to maintain records of all enemies made
game_thread = threading.Thread(target=Gameplay)
game_thread.start()
enemy_spawner_thread = threading.Thread(target=EnemySpawn)
enemy_spawner_thread.start()
```

The key points to note are the use of `enemy_list` being in the global space and then calling it into functions with `global enemy_list` so they are accessing the same list object. The class does essentially the same thing you were doing in your function, but gives the enemies random spawn points. As @Rabbid pointed out, you need to draw the enemies in the same part of your code that draws the background.

P.S. You should not use `Gameplay = threading.Thread(target=Gameplay)` as this overwrites your function. I've implemented a different variable for the thread in my code

Comment: Do you mean freezing if you want to close the window? This can be solved by actually setting up the quit button. When it is not set up it does practically nothing. I implemented it in the Gameplay while True loop.                                                     
 `for event in pygame.event.get():
            if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                pygame.quit()
                quit()`

Comment: Ok I now see what you mean with irresponsiveness. Fixing the quit button sadly doesn't fix that problem.

Comment: Maybe you could also help out here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56282139/python-how-to-interact-with-class-in-different-method Thanks anyways for all your support @Reedinationer.