# Python - How to interact with class in different method

Tags: python, multithreading, class, pygame

I am having an issue with interacting with a classes variables from within a method. I want to change the position of an object in pygame. This has to be done in a method as i use `threading` which needs its targets to be methods.
How can i target a specific `enemy` in `enemy_list`?

I have tried putting the whole `Enemy` class into the `EnemyMove` Method and it still outputs:

```
AttributeError: type object 'Enemy' has no attribute 'X'
```

Here the Code:

```
import pygame
import threading
from random import randint
from time import sleep

pygame.init()
window = pygame.display.set_mode((900, 900))
bg = pygame.image.load("Background.png").convert()

class Enemy:
    def __init__(self):
        self.W = 50
        self.H = 50
        self.X = 420
        self.Y = 850

def Gameplay():
    global enemy_list
    speed=2
    while True:
        window.blit(bg, [0, 0])
        for enemy in enemy_list:
            pygame.draw.rect(window, (255, 50, 49), (enemy.X, enemy.Y, enemy.W, enemy.H))
        pygame.display.update()

def EnemySpawn():
    global enemy_list
    while True: # make enemies forever
        print("Spawned an enemy")
        enemy_list.append(Enemy()) # make an instance of our class
        sleep(randint(1, 5))

def EnemyMove():
    print(Enemy.X) #ISSUE OCURS HERE

enemy_list = [] # to maintain records of all enemies made
enemyMovement_thread = threading.Thread(target=EnemyMove)
enemyMovement_thread.start()
game_thread = threading.Thread(target=Gameplay)
game_thread.start()
enemy_spawner_thread = threading.Thread(target=EnemySpawn)
enemy_spawner_thread.start()
```

What am I doing wrong? Why does it work in `Gameplay` but not in `EnemyMove`?

Comment: `Enemy.X` and `Enemy().X` are not the same. Read back on the difference between a class and an instance, and between class attribute and instance attribute

Comment: `print(Enemy.X)` doesn't make sense.

Comment: you should create instance - ie. `e = Enemy()` and later use it `print(e.X)`. If you have enemies in `enemy_list` then you should use `for enemy in enemy_list: print(enemy.X)` - like you do in `Gameplay`

Comment: mostly game in PyGame can be created without `threading`. You have to only learn how to build `mainloop`. And there is better control of objects then with `threating` because `threads` in Python doesn't run at the same time and one thread blocks other threads.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't simply call `Enemy.X` because `Enemy` is a class definition. In the other line you have `for enemy in enemy_list` which calls upon all the *instances* of `Enemy` (instances are different and here they are `enemy` with a lowercase). To follow a player you would first need a player in your code! I would also recommend you don't use a new thread for each functionality of your game. You can throw in your logic to move enemies into your normal game loop which already has its own thread.

```
import pygame
import threading
from random import randint
from time import sleep

pygame.init()
window = pygame.display.set_mode((900, 900))
bg = pygame.image.load("Background.png").convert()

class Enemy:
    def __init__(self):
        self.W = 50
        self.H = 50
        self.X = 420
        self.Y = 850
        self.speed = 1

class Player: # make a new class so players can have better stats
    def __init__(self):
        self.W = 50
        self.H = 50
        self.X = 300
        self.Y = 300
        self.speed = 10

def Gameplay():
    global enemy_list
    global player
    while True:
        window.blit(bg, [0, 0])
        pygame.draw.rect(window, (255, 255, 255), (player.X, player.Y, player.W, player.H))
        for enemy in enemy_list:
            if enemy.X > player.X:
                enemy.X = enemy.X - enemy.speed
            else:
                enemy.X = enemy.X + enemy.speed
            if enemy.Y > player.Y:
                enemy.Y = enemy.Y - enemy.speed
            else:
                enemy.Y = enemy.Y + enemy.speed
            pygame.draw.rect(window, (255, 50, 49), (enemy.X, enemy.Y, enemy.W, enemy.H))
        pygame.display.update()

def EnemySpawn():
    global enemy_list
    while True: # make enemies forever
        print("Spawned an enemy")
        enemy_list.append(Enemy()) # make an instance of our class
        sleep(randint(1, 5))

if __name__ == "__main__":
    player = Player() # notice the difference in capitalization!
    enemy_list = [] # to maintain records of all enemies made
    game_thread = threading.Thread(target=Gameplay)
    game_thread.start()
    enemy_spawner_thread = threading.Thread(target=EnemySpawn)
    enemy_spawner_thread.start()
```

As @furas notes though you may be better off with just a `mainloop` that has sub-functions to check all these things! I suspect the next thing you would want to do is implement a keyboard listener to allow your `player` to move.

Also note that at this point we have two classes that look ***very*** similar. We will probably benefit from having a base class (let's say `Human`) that both these classes inherit from. In this way we can add a trait to *both* classes with a single line of code. The child classes can still overwrite the values supplied though if needed:

```
import pygame
import threading
from random import randint
from time import sleep

pygame.init()
window = pygame.display.set_mode((900, 900))
bg = pygame.image.load("Video & Image Processing/Image Processing/InputImage.jpg").convert()

class Human:
    def __init__(self):
        self.W = 50
        self.H = 50
        self.X = 420
        self.Y = 850
        self.speed = 1

class Enemy(Human): # inherit Human
    def __init__(self):
        Human.__init__(self) # get all traits a Human has

class Player(Human): # inherit Human
    def __init__(self):
        Human.__init__(self) # get all traits a Human has
        self.X = 300 # overwrite specific traits
        self.Y = 300

def Gameplay():
    global enemy_list
    global player
    while True:
        window.blit(bg, [0, 0])
        pygame.draw.rect(window, (255, 255, 255), (player.X, player.Y, player.W, player.H))
        for enemy in enemy_list:
            if enemy.X > player.X:
                enemy.X = enemy.X - enemy.speed
            else:
                enemy.X = enemy.X + enemy.speed
            if enemy.Y > player.Y:
                enemy.Y = enemy.Y - enemy.speed
            else:
                enemy.Y = enemy.Y + enemy.speed
            pygame.draw.rect(window, (255, 50, 49), (enemy.X, enemy.Y, enemy.W, enemy.H))
        pygame.display.update()

def EnemySpawn():
    global enemy_list
    while True: # make enemies forever
        print("Spawned an enemy")
        enemy_list.append(Enemy()) # make an instance of our class
        sleep(randint(1, 5))


if __name__ == "__main__":
    player = Player() # notice the difference in capitalization!
    enemy_list = [] # to maintain records of all enemies made
    game_thread = threading.Thread(target=Gameplay)
    game_thread.start()
    enemy_spawner_thread = threading.Thread(target=EnemySpawn)
    enemy_spawner_thread.start()
```

Comment: Could you explain to me what the last if statement does? Btw. I have now implemented moving of the player through pygame's key event.

Comment: Assuming you are asking about `if __name__ == "__main__"` it makes it so if you import your code in another script that section won't run. In this way you can say `import mygame` (assuming you save it as mygame.py) and then you will have access to `EnemySpawn()`, `Human()`, etc. If you do not protect your code inside this statement, when you import it your game will run.

Comment: @Varvalian Also, congrats on hitting 15 rep! You can now up-vote questions / answers you find useful! Again, welcome to StackOverflow XD!

Comment: Good to know ^^ I started this project and watched a video about hitbox collision but couldn't understand a thing. Now everything seems much more clear.

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to reach X as it is static member of the `Enemy` class, which is wrong as it is attribute of class **instance** (object). To reach it you need to use object, which is what you keep stored in `enemy_list` list.

Comment: And how do I reach the enemies individually? I want to make them follow the player but right now they are all on the same spot. @Marcin Orlowski