# PyGame: Timer resets every time the mouse is moved

Tags: python, timer, pygame, reset, mousemove

I am currently writing a game that requires a timer. I have written some code that appears to work, as in it counts upward in seconds, but when I move the mouse, the timer resets back to zero and starts counting up again. Obviously, this is not what I want to happen, and I've tried figuring out why this happens instead of counting up continuously, but I could not solve it.

**My code is:**

```
passed_time = 0
timer_started = False
```

(^outside the while loop)

(/ inside while loop)

```
    for event in ev:
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            is_alive = False
        if start_clicked:
            timer_started = True
            if timer_started:
                start_time = pygame.time.get_ticks()
            if won:
                timer_started = False
    if timer_started:
        passed_time = pygame.time.get_ticks() - start_time
    text = font.render(str(passed_time / 1000), True, font_color)
    screen.blit(text, (20, 450))
```

as well as mouse events that set [**start_clicked**] or [**won**] to True when their respective colors are clicked.

From my basic knowledge of timers in PyGame, this should keep counting up once **start_clicked** is set to true, however it just resets every time the mouse is moved, which completely defeats the point of a timer on a mouse-movement based avoider game. What can I do to fix this and make it run continuously, until the **won** variable is true?

And if for whatever reason I didn't include enough to figure out the issue, [the full code is here:](https://pastebin.com/S7B45Js3)

Comment: Under what situation does `start_clicked` become true?  The timer is re-starting whenever this is set, is this how it's supposed to work?

Comment: @Kingsley start_clicked is true when a specific color is clicked on (0,0,255) or blue, when it's clicked once it stays true until the win color is clicked, but I don't know why it would think the variable is set every time the mouse moves, since it appears that nothing else does this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By looking at your full code, your event loop is wrong, because your identation is off.

Currently you have `if event.type == pygame.QUIT:` in the event loop, and all the other `if event.type == whatever` outside it because they are not indented enough.

All the `if`s checking the events must be inside the event loop, while `if`s unrelated to the event loop (like `if start_clicked:`) must be outside, typically after, the event loop.

I cannot fix all your code, but fixing the event loop will surely help.

Comment: Okay I somewhat fixed my timer now, it stops resetting every time the mouse moves. I'm not sure exactly what I did, but basically, I copy & pasted the code for a timer from a website, but I must've switched some stuff around at some point which made it not work, but I fixed it now. Now is there any way to reset [pygame.time.get_ticks()] back to zero? Once I progress onto the next stage and start the timer again, it resumes counting the total time the program has been running, instead of restarting the timer from zero

Comment: No. [pygame.time.get_ticks()](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/time.html#pygame.time.get_ticks) does exactly what you have said. It returns the number of milliseconds since `pygame.init()` was called. You can store the previous value and do the math yourself. But to track time I would recommend using [Clock](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/time.html#pygame.time.Clock). You still need to do some math, but will be probably easier.

Comment: [This question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/45520104/10426037) may be useful to see how to use `Clock`.