# Pygame: How to make something happen after 10 seconds using time.clock?

Tags: python, time, pygame, clock

```
if (time.clock() > 10: 
    DO SOMETHING
```

this only works with 1 iteration of the function then the time.clock surpasses 10seconds.

How do I do:

```
 if (time.clock > time.clock + 10):
```

how do I save a value for the clock at a particular instance??

I have already tried the get_time() function although this doesn't work on the account that python throws an attribute error

Comment: Better use one of these solutions: [`pygame.time.get_ticks`, `pygame.time.set_timer` or the `delta time (dt)` variant)](https://stackoverflow.com/q/30720665/6220679). Also, `time.clock` is deprecated since Python 3.3.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Countdown timer in Pygame](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30720665/countdown-timer-in-pygame)

Answer (score 3):

You can save time.clock in a variable

```
first_instance = time.clock()
if (time.clock > first_instance + 10):
```

Comment: first instance + 10 will forever be larger than time.clock

Answer (score 0):

you could rather do

```
import time

time.sleep(10)
#do something.
```

Answer (score 0):

You could also use the modulus operator

```
if(time.clock() % 10 == 0)
#do something
```

But this will make something happen after every 10th second, and also at the 0th second. But the benefit would be being able to change the behavior to work every 11th second for example which maybe would be preferable or every 12th second. For example every 15th second would be:

```
if(time.clock() % 15 == 0)
#do something
```