# Pygame: how to load 150 images and present each one for only .5sec per trial

Tags: pygame

I'm currently trying to develop a psychology experiment which involves having 150 .tif images that need to be presented for 0.5sec per trial, full screen, after a noise has been heard. Each image needs to be presented at least once before being presented again. I am completing my experiment within pygame.

I've been thinking about saving all the images into a directory and then pulling them each out one by one. Does this seem like a good idea?

I'm very new to programming and would appreciate any help/links to similar questions. If I'm missing any relevant information please let me know.

Thank you!

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please ask only one specific question at a time and also try to solve your problem on your own first and then show us what's not working. Take a look at the [help center](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [this checklist](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/260648/6220679).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Use the [`glob`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/glob.html) module to get a list of your image filenames: https://pymotw.com/3/glob/index.html
2. Loop over this list of filenames, load them with [`pygame.image.load`](http://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/image.html#pygame.image.load) and append the resulting images/`pygame.Surface`s to a list.
3. Shuffle the list, create an index variable (`index = 0`) and assign the image at the current index to another variable, e.g. `current_image = image_list[index]`.
4. Use a timer variable to increment the index and swap the image after the desired time interval [check out the `pygame.time.get_ticks`, `set_timer` or `delta time` solutions here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/30720665/6220679).
5. If the index is `>=` the length of the list, reset it to `0` and shuffle the list again.

Comment: Hi I've been trying to follow your advice to the best of my ability but I'm stuck at step 2. This is my code:
`import pygame, glob
types= ('*.tif')
artfile_names= [ ]
for files in types:
    artfile_names.extend(glob.glob(files))

print(artfile_names)

for artworks in artfile_names:
    pygame.image.load(str(artfile_names))`

but it gives the error of not being able to open my files. Could you give a reason as to why?