# Changing value of a variable or bool once after specified amount of time?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pygame

I want to change the value of a `bool` after some time when a user hits enter, whilst keeping the program running.

Pygame's delay or timers don't work as they stop the whole code or repeats a user event over and over again.

Comment: You need to share what you have tried to code in your question details.

Comment: i couldn't think of anything there really wasn't any specific code i could use

Comment: Share the code for what you tried to do and explain why it did not work. People want to see that you have made an attempt.

Comment: Have you tried one of these [timers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30720665/countdown-timer-in-pygame)?

Comment: i'm sorry but i haven't made any attempts because straight up the timers 
and delay in pygame stops the whole code which is not what i want

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Although pygame has no function to wait while allowing the program to run, there are several ways of doing it without pygame. You can import time, a module that comes with python used for getting the current time. It has a function, `time.time()` which returns the amount of seconds since a set time. Therefore, you can do `x = time.time()` when the user hits enter, and you continuously check to see if `time.time() - x <= delay` in the game loop, and change the value of your boolean if it is true. For example:

```
import pygame, time, sys
screen = pygame.display.set_mode((100,100))
timer = False # timer is true after the user hits enter and before your boolean changes
delay = 1 # whatever your delay is (seconds)
bool = False
while True: # game loop
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            pygame.quit()
            sys.exit()
        if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN and event.key == pygame.K_RETURN:
            x = time.time() # x is the time when you press enter
            timer = True # the timer is activated
    print(bool)
    if timer:
        if time.time() - x >= delay: # if the amount of time since enter was pressed is the delay
            bool = True #change bool value
```

This code will wait till you press enter, and then, one second later, change the boolean. If you add anything in the game loop, it will still run while the timer is active. This works because `time.time()` gets the current time, and if the difference between the current time and the time when the user pressed enter (represented as `x`) is equal to the delay, then that much time passed since the user hit enter and it it changes the boolean.

Comment: hmm i see but it seems to change it immediately after i press enter, does he delay need to be in miliseconds?

Comment: That was because the code wasn't made properly. I fixed it so now you can run it and see that it works. Earlier, I wrote `if time.time() - x <= delay` instead of `if time.time() - x >= delay`. I also changed it so you can run it.