# pygame.display.update() doesn't work well

Tags: python, python-3.x, pygame

I was programming pygame in Mac. Then, there was a problem.
I wrote the code like below, but pygame.display.update() doesn't work.
It should update and wait 3 seconds, but it wait 3 seconds first, and it updates after pygame.quit().
Can anyone tell me how to solve this problem?

this doesn't work:

```
import pygame
import sys

pygame.init()

win = pygame.display.set_mode((500, 500))
pygame.display.set_caption("hello")
font = pygame.font.SysFont("comicsans", 100)
text = font.render("hello", 1, (255, 255, 255))
win.blit(text, (200, 200))
pygame.display.update()
pygame.time.delay(3000)

pygame.quit()
sys.exit(0)
```

this works normaly:

```
import pygame
import sys

pygame.init()

win = pygame.display.set_mode((500, 500))
pygame.display.set_caption("hello")
font = pygame.font.SysFont("comicsans", 100)
text = font.render("hello", 1, (255, 255, 255))
win.blit(text, (200, 200))
pygame.display.update()

pygame.quit()
pygame.time.delay(3000)
sys.exit(0)
```

OS: Mac
Python Version 3.8.3
Pygame Version 1.9.6
Editor: Jupyter Notebook

Comment: This is also similar: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50219028/pygame-display-update-does-not-update-until-after-clock-delay?rq=1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue is on MacOS (and potentially other OS's), the screen only updates after pygame events are checked.

Normally, this is done by calling `pygame.event.get()` or `pygame.event.poll()`.

However, if your program doesn't care about checking events, then a call to `pygame.event.pump()` will work as well.

This issue is briefly mentioned in the documentation for `pygame.event.pump()`, [link here](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/event.html#pygame.event.pump).

> There are important things that must be dealt with internally in the
> event queue. The main window may need to be repainted or respond to
> the system. If you fail to make a call to the event queue for too
> long, the system may decide your program has locked up.

So the solution is to call `pygame.event.pump()` (or another event function) after `pygame.display.update()`.

That the corrected code would then be:

```
import pygame
import sys

pygame.init()

win = pygame.display.set_mode((500, 500))
pygame.display.set_caption("hello")
font = pygame.font.SysFont("comicsans", 100)
text = font.render("hello", 1, (255, 255, 255))
win.blit(text, (200, 200))
pygame.display.update()
pygame.event.pump() # Make sure events are handled
pygame.time.delay(3000)

pygame.quit()
sys.exit(0)
```

Comment: Thanks! But, when I tried this in Atom, it doesn't work. Can you tell me why?

Comment: Not sure what to tell you. It works for me in Atom, with the script package. Does it work at the command line? Is there an error message?

Comment: Sorry, I fixed it! I installed pygame 2.0.0.dev6 and it works!