# Crashing Loading Bar in Python

Tags: python, pygame

Me and my acquaintance are working on creating a loading bar that takes forever to load for the fun of it. However, when making this loading bar, it seems to crash within the first second or two. Here's the code:

```
import pygame
import time
import random

pygame.init()

progress = 0

black = [0, 0, 0]
white = [255, 255, 255]
green = [0, 255, 0]

screenWidth = 600
screenHeigth = 800
size = [screenWidth, screenHeigth]

font = pygame.font.SysFont("Comic Sans MS", 25)

clock = pygame.time.Clock()

screen = pygame.display.set_mode(size)
pygame.display.set_caption('Loading...')


def textObjecte(text, color, size):
    if size == "small":
        textsuraface = font.render(text, True, color)

        return textsuraface, textsuraface.get_rect()


def loading(progress):
    if progress < 100:
        text = font.render("loading: " + str(int(progress)) + "%", True, green)

    screen.blit(text, (300, 100))


def message_to_screen(msg, color, y_displace, size="small"):
    textSurf, textRect = textObjecte(msg, color, size)
    textRect.center = (screenWidth/2), (screenHeigth/2) + y_displace

screen.blit(textSurf, textRect)


while progress/2 < 100:
    timeCount = random.randint(15, 30)
    increase = random.randint(1, 7)
    progress += increase
    screen.fill(black)
    pygame.draw.rect(screen, white, [300, 50, 200, 50])
    pygame.draw.rect(screen, black, [301, 51, 198, 48])

    if (progress/2) > 100:
        pygame.draw.rect(screen, white, [302, 52, 196, 46])
    else:
        pygame.draw.rect(screen, white, [302, 52, progress, 46])

    loading(progress/2)
    pygame.display.flip()

    time.sleep(timeCount)
```

Any help with the code would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: What's the error message/crash log you are getting?

Comment: our exit code is -805306369

Comment: Well, the game consumes a huge load of RAM ~400MBs, which hangs my system. I am also getting no error as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two things that need to be changed:

1. You've got to handle the events (empty the event queue) each frame or the window will become unresponsive. Either call [`pygame.event.pump()`](http://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/event.html#pygame.event.pump) or add an event loop `for event in pygame.event.get():`.
2. You have to remove the `time.sleep` call, because it blocks the program, the events can't be handled and the window will freeze as well (for the specified time).

I'm not sure what you're trying to achieve with the `time.sleep`, but there's most likely a better way.

Comment: 2. We will try the time.sleep thing.

Comment: You have to change both.

Comment: 3. Change of plans. We are going to add the pump.

Comment: If you need some kind of timer, check out these answers: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30720665/countdown-timer-in-pygame Also, call `clock.tick(fps)` each frame to limit the frame rate.

Comment: I still have a question though: We are going to need a time delay. Can you think of a way to accomplish this.

Answer (score 0):

Your issue is that TextSurf is defined in a function then your trying to use it outside of the function which breaks it.

```
def message_to_screen(msg, color, y_displace, size="small"):
    textSurf, textRect = textObjecte(msg, color, size)
    textRect.center = (screenWidth/2), (screenHeigth/2) + y_displace

screen.blit(textSurf, textRect)
```

what you would want it to indent `$ screen.blit(textSurf, textRect)` so its inside the function

Comment: this is a typo in our ide it's not like that