# pygame.time.wait() crashes the program

Tags: python, python-3.x, pygame

In a pygame code I wannted to do a title that changes colors. 
I tried to do a simple title that changes colors, but it not even turned the color to blue (or do it for a second), and the program crash. The code:

```
title_font = pygame.font.SysFont("monospace", TITLE_SIZE)

while True:
    title = title_font.render("game", 5, RED)
    game_display.blit(title, TITLE_POS)
    pygame.display.update()
    pygame.time.wait(2000)

    title = title_font.render("game", 5, BLUE)
    game_display.blit(title, TITLE_POS)
    pygame.display.update()
    pygame.time.wait(3000)

    title = title_font.render("game", 5, RED)
    game_display.blit(title, TITLE_POS)
    pygame.display.update()
    pygame.time.wait(2000)
```

It also happens with pygame.time.delay(), and I don't know where is the problem...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Don't use `pygame.time.wait` or `delay` because these functions make your program sleep for the given time and the window becomes unresponsive. You also need to handle the events (with one of the [pygame.event](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/event.html#pygame.event.pump) functions) each frame to avoid this.

Here are some timer examples which don't block: [Countdown timer in Pygame](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30720665/countdown-timer-in-pygame)

To switch the colors, you can just assign the next color to a variable and use it to render the text.

```
import pygame


pygame.init()
screen = pygame.display.set_mode((640, 480))
clock = pygame.time.Clock()
title_font = pygame.font.SysFont('monospace', 50)
BACKGROUND_COLOR = pygame.Color('gray12')
BLUE = pygame.Color('blue')
RED = pygame.Color('red')
# Assign the current color to the color variable.
color = RED
timer = 2
dt = 0

done = False
while not done:
    # Handle the events.
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        # This allows the user to quit by pressing the X button.
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            done = True

    timer -= dt  # Decrement the timer by the delta time.
    if timer <= 0:  # When the time is up ...
        # Swap the colors.
        if color == RED:
            color = BLUE
            timer = 3
        else:
            color = RED
            timer = 2

    screen.fill(BACKGROUND_COLOR)
    title = title_font.render('game', 5, color)
    screen.blit(title, (200, 50))

    pygame.display.flip()
    # dt is the passed time since the last clock.tick call.
    dt = clock.tick(60) / 1000  # / 1000 to convert milliseconds to seconds.

pygame.quit()
```