# How would I slowly print something across the screen Pygame?

Tags: python, pygame

I am programming a game where when you discover a new area I want the name of it to slowly be typed across the screen, I have tried it with

```
time.sleep(1)
```

but that causes the whole program to stop for a second and I still want to be able to move around.

Comment: Take a look at this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53462742/how-can-i-make-text-in-pygame-pan-letter-by-letter

Comment: @Andrej I think you've misunderstood the question. The text position should be animated not the text itself.