# pygame: send custom event with attributes via pygame.time.set_timer()

Tags: python, pygame

I am blitting highlightings in a game. Along with that I want to set a timer for firing a custom event which tells the main driver to remove those highlightings after x milliseconds. like so:

```
REMOVE_HIGHLIGHT_EVENT = p.USEREVENT + 1

coords = (3, 5)  # the coordinates of the highlighted square

pygame.time.set_timer(p.event.Event(REMOVE_HIGHLIGHT_EVENT, square=coords).type, milliseconds=2000, once=True)
```

and in the main loop:

```
while running:
    for e in pygame.event.get():
        ...
        if e.type == REMOVE_HIGHLIGHT_EVENT:
                removeHighlight(e.square)
```

But I am getting `AttributeError: 'Event' object has no attribute 'square'`.

So apparently I cannot set the attribute this way. I have thought about encoding the coordinates I want to give along in the integer representing the event type, but that seems really unpythonic to me. Is there a better way to pass this information along?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You've misunderstood how [`pygame.time.set_timer()`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/time.html#pygame.time.set_timer) works. The instruction

> ```py
> pygame.time.set_timer(p.event.Event(REMOVE_HIGHLIGHT_EVENT, square=coords).type, milliseconds=2000, once=True)
> ```

doesn't make any sense. In fact, you are creating a temporary event object that goes nowhere. You're trying to invent a feature that doesn't exist.

You cannot attach a custom [`pygame.event.Event()`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/event.html#pygame.event.Event) object to a timer event. `set_timer` has 2 arguments, the event id and the time, but nothing else. See [Timer in Pygame](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30720665/countdown-timer-in-pygame/63551239#63551239).
The only way to post a customer event is [`pygame.event.post()`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/event.html#pygame.event.post).